# Any way to still be able to use an insecure API connection (React)?

Tags: reactjs, http, heroku, https

I have spent a bit of time making this and it works well locally but on the server it breaks due to the below error. The API I am using seems to be on an insecure 'http:' address so the browser won't allow it's connection as my website is on an 'https' address. Is there any way to get around this with some kind of proxy/heroku thing?

[Github](https://github.com/AGrush/Pet-adoption-app-React-v16)

[The broken app website](https://agwebdesign.net/react/petadoption/)

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://agwebdesign.net/react/petadoption/' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure script
>   'http://api.petfinder.com/pet.find?key=920cf4ddd938497ba32bef47b7f35080&format=json&output=full&location=Seattle%2C%20WA&animal=&breed=&callback=jsonp_jfg1sgfprug5jl1'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to do this? You should be using HTTPS everywhere. With tools like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) there's no longer any excuse not to.

In any case, that particular URL seems to also be served over HTTPS. Simply change the protocol from `http://` to `https://` and it should stop getting blocked.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me on react 16.12 hosted on [vercel](https://vercel.com/) with a backend using an insecure 'HTTP:' address

Step 1. Go to the website's information section (the "i" button on the left-right corner, beside your URL)

[image: step1]

Step 2. Scroll down to the "insecure content" and choose "allow" from the dropdown

[image: step2]

step 3. Refresh your page and you're good to go